# I want my button to call my modal once the fields filled

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I would like some help to figure the easier way to summon my modal only once those fields are filled:

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_send" />

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:name">Full Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" placeholder="Full name" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="contact:name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:compagny">Compagny Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" placeholder="Compagny Name" class="form-control" name="compagny" id="contact:compagny">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:email">Email</label>
                                            <input required type="email" value="" placeholder="email@email.com" class="form-control" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" id="contact:email">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="contact:phone">Phone *</label>
                                            <input type="tel" value="" class="form-control input-phone" placeholder="999 999-9999" name="phone" id="contact:phone" pattern="[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" maxlength="12" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69">
                                        </div>
                            </form>
```

This is my button:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> SEND MESSAGE</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And this is my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        ...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                     </div>
```

So far, my button is trigerring the modal with the fields unfilled, I know I need some javascript code, as a beginner without any experiences at all, i'm struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `blur` event listeners to each `input` element in the form and the modal trigger button and loop over all of the inputs to show the modal if they all have non-empty values. You will also need to remove the `data-target` attribute from the modal trigger button and only open the modal programmatically. This will cause the modal to open once the user clicks away from the last input that they fill in.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
const inputs = [...form.querySelectorAll("input")];
const modalTrigger = document.querySelector("button[type=submit]");
inputs.forEach(input=>{
    input.addEventListener("blur", openModalIfAllFilled);
});
function openModalIfAllFilled(){
 const allFilled = inputs.every(a=>a.value.trim());
  if(allFilled){
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  }
}
modalTrigger.addEventListener("click", openModalIfAllFilled);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form action="" id="myForm">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_send" />

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:name">Full Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" placeholder="Full name" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="contact:name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:compagny">Compagny Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" placeholder="Compagny Name" class="form-control" name="compagny" id="contact:compagny">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:email">Email</label>
                                            <input required type="email" value="" placeholder="email@email.com" class="form-control" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" id="contact:email">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="contact:phone">Phone *</label>
                                            <input type="tel" value="" class="form-control input-phone" placeholder="999 999-9999" name="phone" id="contact:phone" pattern="[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" maxlength="12" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69">
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                            </form>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary active"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> SEND MESSAGE</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        ...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                     </div>
```

This can also be written with only jQuery for better browser support.

```js
$("#myForm input").blur(openModalIfAllFilled);
$("button[type=submit]").click(openModalIfAllFilled);
function openModalIfAllFilled(){
 var notAllFilled = $('#myForm input').is(function(index, element){
   return !element.value.trim();
  });
  if(!notAllFilled){
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form action="" id="myForm">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_send" />

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:name">Full Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" placeholder="Full name" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="contact:name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:compagny">Compagny Name *</label>
                                            <input required type="text" value="" placeholder="Compagny Name" class="form-control" name="compagny" id="contact:compagny">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label for="contact:email">Email</label>
                                            <input required type="email" value="" placeholder="email@email.com" class="form-control" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" id="contact:email">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="contact:phone">Phone *</label>
                                            <input type="tel" value="" class="form-control input-phone" placeholder="999 999-9999" name="phone" id="contact:phone" pattern="[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" maxlength="12" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69">
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                            </form>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary active"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> SEND MESSAGE</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        ...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must be doing something wrong because... the modal still shows up...

Comment: @OlivierGodbout What do you mean? Does the snippet in my answer not work?

Comment: @OlivierGodbout Could you explain what part of its behavior is incorrect? It is working fine for me.

Comment: For example when I run snippet, I don't fill any fields, press send message and the modal shows up!

Comment: @OlivierGodbout I have edited my answer. See if it works for you now.

Comment: And when I run it throught my website there is an error on this line : const inputs = [...form.querySelectorAll("input")];

Comment: @OlivierGodbout What browser and version are you using?

Comment: @OlivierGodbout No problem!